# How to Append a new line in each element of a string array?

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem with string array. please help me here. I have a string like below:

```
string[] str1;
str1 = new string[5]{ “Element 1”, “Element 2”, “Element 3”, “Element 4”, “Element 5” };
```

Here, I want to check each element in the string array has a new line or not. If it doesn't have a new line, append to it, I need to append the new line characters like below:

```
str1 = new string[5]{ “Element 1\n”, “Element 2\n”, “Element 3\n”, “Element 4\n”, “Element 5\n” };
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question

**Given**

```
var str1 = new string[5] { "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4", "Element 5" };
```

It could be as simple as

```
str1 = str1.Select(x => x.TrimEnd("\n") + "\n").ToArray();
```

Which makes sure every element has a "\n" appended

---

or

```
str1 = str1.Select(x => x.EndsWith("\n") ? x : x + "\n").ToArray();
```

---

or

```
str1 = str1.Select(x => x.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine) ? x : x + Environment.NewLine).ToArray();
```

<sub>*More Platform independent*</sub>

---

As a guess, it's more than likely you just need to add the *NewLine*, when you are writing it to a textbox/file/Console, with `string.Join`, and can keep your array clean of that sort of thing

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, str));
```

Comment: This approach also removes e.g. space at the beginning of each element how about `str1 = str1.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('\n') + "\n").ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

using `LINQ`

```
str1 = str1.Select(e => e.EndsWith("\n") ? e : e + "\n")
           .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop, you may do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
{
    if (!str1[i].EndsWith("\n"))
    {
        str1[i] += "\n";
    }
}
```

That being said, you should consider changing the name of your variable. `str1` isn't a good name for an array (or even for a string in most situations).

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] str1 = { "Element 1","Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4", "Element 5" };
        string[] newstr1;
        var b="";
        for(int i=0;i<str1.Length;i++)
        {
            var chck1 = str1[i];
            if (!chck1.Contains("\n"))
            {

                b += chck1 +"\n ,";
            }
         }
        b = b.TrimEnd(',');
        var nwstrg = b.Split(',');
```